# problem in making records of a file by perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying putting a file into records with number starting from record 0 to n and saving it into an output file. my file is starting from AA to // and there are several AA's and //  so I'm putting record number for each AA to // as there are 2000 to 3000 AA's so I want to put them in records with number. Could someone please help me.

//

AA  r00001

FA  tea

OS  fskjkterjykjlt

//

AA  T00002

FA  ACE2

OS  coffee

SQ  MDNVVDPWYINPSGFAKDTQDEEYVQHHDNVNPTIPPPDNYILNNENDDGLDNLLGMDYY

//

AA  T00003

FA  Diet coke

OS  ewtji34ut893u569

SQ  MTSICSSKFQQQHYQLTNSNIFLLQHQHHHQTQQHQLIAPKIPLGTSQLQNMQQSQQSNV

//

AA  T00004

FA  coke

OS  jgerjgkhjetkh

SQ  MKNNNNTTKSTTMSSSVLSTNETFPTTINSATKIFRYQHIMPAPSPLIPGGNQNQ

SQ  RLRQHIPQSIITDLTKGGGRGPHKKISKVDTLRIAVEYIRSLQDLVDDLNGGSNIGANNA

//

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ifh;

my $ofh;

my $line;
my $recnum = 0;
my $ifn  = "factor data 1.txt";
my $ofn  = "try.txt";
open ($ifh, "<$ifn") || die "can't open $ifn";
open ($ofh, ">$ofn") or die "can't open $ofn";
my $a = "\/\/ ";

while ($line = <$ifh>)
{
chomp $line ;

    if ($line =~ m/$a\$/)
        {

         print "$ofh $line\n";

         $recnum++;
  }
         else
 {
        print "$ofh $recnum $line\n";
  }
 }
       close ($ifh);
       close ($ofh);
```

Comment: Please show us your desired output.

Comment: You'll want to add a Perl tag to the question to get more answers.

Answer (score 1):

These types of record I/O problems are simplified if you use the Perl idiom of changing the record separator.  Now each record becomes a line and lines are easy to count.

NOTE: I also removed the last // so we don't count the empty record.

Ok... I'm guessing that you may want something like this

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

 use strict;
 use warnings;

 my $cntr = 0;

 print "Starting\n";

 # change record seperator
 $/ = '//';

 while ((<DATA>))
 {
   print"============== Record number $cntr ======================\n";
   print "$_\n";
   print "========================================================\n";

   $cntr++;  
 }

 exit 0;


 __DATA__

 /

 AA r00001

 FA tea

 OS fskjkterjykjlt

 //

 AA T00002

 FA ACE2

 OS coffee

 SQ MDNVVDPWYINPSGFAKDTQDEEYVQHHDNVNPTIPPPDNYILNNENDDGLDNLLGMDYY

 //

 AA T00003

 FA Diet coke

 OS ewtji34ut893u569

 SQ MTSICSSKFQQQHYQLTNSNIFLLQHQHHHQTQQHQLIAPKIPLGTSQLQNMQQSQQSNV

 //

 AA T00004

 FA coke

 OS jgerjgkhjetkh

 SQ MKNNNNTTKSTTMSSSVLSTNETFPTTINSATKIFRYQHIMPAPSPLIPGGNQNQ

 SQ RLRQHIPQSIITDLTKGGGRGPHKKISKVDTLRIAVEYIRSLQDLVDDLNGGSNIGANNA

 //
```

With output like this

```
 Starting
 ============== Record number 0 ======================

 /

 AA r00001

 FA tea

 OS fskjkterjykjlt

 //
 ========================================================
 ============== Record number 1 ======================


 AA T00002

 FA ACE2

 OS coffee

 SQ MDNVVDPWYINPSGFAKDTQDEEYVQHHDNVNPTIPPPDNYILNNENDDGLDNLLGMDYY

 //
 ========================================================
 ============== Record number 2 ======================


 AA T00003

 FA Diet coke

 OS ewtji34ut893u569

 SQ MTSICSSKFQQQHYQLTNSNIFLLQHQHHHQTQQHQLIAPKIPLGTSQLQNMQQSQQSNV

 //
 ========================================================
 ============== Record number 3 ======================


 AA T00004

 FA coke

 OS jgerjgkhjetkh

 SQ MKNNNNTTKSTTMSSSVLSTNETFPTTINSATKIFRYQHIMPAPSPLIPGGNQNQ

 SQ RLRQHIPQSIITDLTKGGGRGPHKKISKVDTLRIAVEYIRSLQDLVDDLNGGSNIGANNA
```